# How can I copy every n files to a different folder

Tags: python, copy, shutil

I have a folder with 20 photos and the names of these photos are respectively `image1.png, image2.png, ..., image20.png`. I want to copy these photos into four different folders. For example in `Folder1` will be `image1.png, image2.png, image3.png, image4.png`.
In `Folder2` will be `image5.png, image6.png, image7.png, image8.png` and so on...

This is what I tried but can't really get the logic right:

```
import shutil

for x in range(1,20): 
    for i in range(1,5): 
        source = "image" + str(i) + ".png" 
        destination = "Folder" + str(x) + "/image" + str(i) + ".png"
        dest = shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

Comment: Does any error occur? If yes, please provide the error.

Answer (score 0):

To get the folder's index you can simply divide the file's index by how many files you want to have in each folder. For example:

```py
import shutil

for image_index in range(20): 
    source = f"image{image_index+1}.png" 
    destination = f"Folder{image_index//4+1}/image{image_index+1}.png"
    dest = shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Introducing [divmod()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod)
you can simplify the code:

```
for x in range(1,20): 
    dirname, filename = divmod(x,5)
    source = "image" + str(i) + ".png" 
    destination = "imagecopy" + str(dirname) + "/image" + str(filename) + ".png"
```

remember that in this way all starts from 0

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a good idea to create the target folders (if necessary). I suggest:

```
import os
import shutil

SOURCE_DIR = os.getcwd()

for i in range(20):
    _image = f'image{i+1}.png'
    _from = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, _image)
    _target = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, f'Folder{i//5+1}')
    os.makedirs(_target, exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copyfile(_from, os.path.join(_target, _image))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this. Assuming you have created the four folders, used integer division to determine the folder number for each image and then use f string to create the file path.

```
import shutil

for i in range(1, 21):
    folder_number = (i - 1) // 4 + 1
    source = f"image{i}.png"
    destination = f"Folder{folder_number}/image{i}.png"
    shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

Comment: OP requires 4 output folders - not 5

Comment: the 4  in the integer division indicates the 4 output folder

Comment: There are 20 images that need to be distributed evenly across 4 folders - i.e., 5 in each. Your code would place 4 files in each of 5 folders

Comment: The code creates four folder, that why the 4, and then copy the corresponding images into each folder of the 4 folders.. The calculation determines the folder number based on the image index. That would place 5 image in each folder.

Comment: I suggest you remove the call to copyfile and replace it with *print(destination)* then run your code and you will see 5 different folder paths. From the original question: "I want to copy these photos into four different folders"

Comment: The code created 4 folders per the original questions

Comment: ...................5

Comment: @DarkKnight to be fair, there's a problem in the question. The OP says they want 4 folders but then shows 4 files In a folder. This gets to a total of 16 files, not 20. It's hard to say whether the mistake is in the amount of folders or amount of files in each. Anyway the denominator should be the amount of files in each folder. Since the question shows 4 files in a folder that makes sense